# Frameworks for numerically solving this specific form of PDE?

Tags: numerical-analysis

are there some packages in any programming language which make it convenient to solve this specific type of PDE?

$f_t + \left(1 + \xi \frac{\kappa_t - a}{T-t}\right) f_a + \frac{\sigma^2}{2} f_{aa} + r(1-\gamma)f - (\rho + \lambda(a))f + \gamma f^{1-\frac{1}{\gamma}} = 0$

I've come across similar PDEs multiple times so i am wondering if there already exists some package to conveniently solve it numerically.